# MySql text search to find similar strings

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find a way to query a particular database table column for similar strings or words.  For example, if I have a string

```
I have a foo bar in my kitchen
```

The query would return results such as...

```
foo fighters are a good band
raise the bar
kitchen remodeling contractors
foo bar is a funny word
```

Can this be done with one query?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are trying to match on any word in your given list.
I would use the "OR" operator.

Example (assuming your table is called `my_table` and the column you are searching is `my_column`):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_column like '%I%'
OR my_column LIKE '%have%'
OR my_column LIKE '%a%'
OR my_column LIKE '%foo%'
OR my_column LIKE '%bar%'
OR my_column LIKE '%in%'
OR my_column LIKE '%my%'
OR my_column LIKE '%kitchen%';
```

However, this query will run very slowly due to the double wildcards.
You can also try http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: ... and perhaps filter out words like "I", "have", "in", "and", "or", etc. while constructing your query.

Comment: I can see that, but the string I'll be searching against will be stored in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

At a basic level, you want to implement a [full-text index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html) on the column, so (assuming your column is col1 and your table is tbl), you'd need to `alter table tbl add fulltext(col1);` and search using `select id from tbl where match(col1) against 'foo' or match(col1) against 'bar' or match(col1) against`kitchen`...` and so on, so forth, as described in [this tutorial](http://devzone.zend.com/26/using-mysql-full-text-searching/). There's nothing wrong with @WinnieTong's answer, it's just that this sort of use case is precisely what a full-text index  was designed for.

When you get beyond the abilities of [mysql](http://www.mysql.com), people generally use [Sphinx](http://sphinx-search.com) or [Apache SoLR](http://lucene.apache.org/solr) to accomplish a searchable index.